# Recessed lights, how to replace bulb?

Tags: recessed-lighting

H[image]

Can I just replace the bulb or do I have to replace the entire assembly? Does the bulb just unscrew or is there a spring mechanism? Also what type of bulb is it? I'd like to replace it with a bright led

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bulb will just unscrew.

That's currently an R30 CFL bulb.  Probably about a 65w watt equivalent.

You should have no problem replacing with LED.